# Настройка visual code для работы с СИ

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

Хочу настроить vs code для программирования на C.

- Скачал компилятор
- Добавил его в PATH
- Установил в vs code плагины C/C++ и code runner
- Поставил галку на "code runner run code in terminal" в настройках.

Нажимаю Ctrl+Alt+N (Run code) и получаю в терминале это:

```
1@DESKTOP-6KBV2HQ MINGW64 /c/Programming
$ cd "c:\Programming\styding\" && gcc main.c -o main && "c:\Programming\styding\"main
bash: cd: c:\Programming\styding" && gcc main.c -o main && c:Programmingstyding"main: No such file or directory
```

В глаза сразу бросилось

```
c:Programmingstyding"main
```

Видимо code runner неправильно составляет имя файла. Подскажите как это исправить.

Можно ли как-то изменить данную команду запуска и компиляции?

Comment: `"c:\\Programming\\styding\\"`

Comment: Дело в том, что вам необходимо использовать пути не с обратным слешем, а с обычным `/`. Ну или двойной обратный.

Comment: Понятное дело, что там слеши перепутаны. Я спрашивал про то, как и где изменить изменить данную команду.